# How do I capitalize all text in a document using the DOM and the toUpperCase function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to capitalize every single paragraph in a website using the document.querySelectorAll() function.

I don't know what parameter to choose so I can get an array of all the texts.

Here is my Code:

```
var txtArr = document.querySelectorAll("p");

function capitalize(txtArr){

    for (var i = 0; i < txtArr.length; i++){
    
        txtArr[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
    
    }

}

capitalize(txtArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
var txtArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p"));

function capitalize(txtArr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < txtArr.length; i++){
    
        txtArr[i].textContent = txtArr[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
    
    }

}

capitalize(txtArr);
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm <3

I removed the Array.from() function because I don't think ill really need it but everything else works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: No problem, but this can be dome with only css if you really only need to transform text from paragraphs to uppercase.```text-transform: capitalize; ```